# Jenkins with RF and AutoIt not working in a minimized or closed Virtual Machine

Tags: selenium, jenkins, virtual-machine, robotframework, autoit

I have Robotframework/Selenium tests running on Windows VMs, and to handle Windows Authentication popups I used a simple AutoItLibrary Send Keys.

The problem is that If I have the remote desktop open (remote Virtual Machine), everything works fine but If I minimize or close the remote VM window, the Send Keys stops working.

I can leave the machine right after script send the keys and the rest of the test just goes well.

How can I handle this situation? I dont want to have to look the test every single run to send the credentials.

**Example:**

```
Login Windows Authentication
    [Documentation]     Windows Authentication using 
    Send    ${USERNAME}
    Send    {TAB}
    Send    ${PASSWORD}
    Send    {ENTER}
```

I also tried this unsuccessfully:

```
http://user:password@example.com
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the windows machine, say if you are doing this with "Administrator" then i would suggest you to create another user "Someuser" with Remote Desktop rights.

Login to windows machine using Remotely using "Someuser" and from this session i.e. "Someuser" open another remote desktop to the same machine by logging in as "Administrator".

By this, the windows machine will always be active as "Administrator" and you should not face that issue! even if you close the remote desktop of "Someuser".

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Been there,done that;) 
In nut shell, what I understand from Windows & VM internals, if there is no active user connected to Windows VM, there will be no desktop environment.This means that any app/service/program which interacts with desktop/GUI will not get proper objects to handle - no menus,no popups, even screen shot will be blank (this is nice exercise to verify above).

For Jenkins under Linux (any VM linux will do) I can propose the following:

- create a separate job which will activate RDP to Windows VMs
- link this job to your main one as a precondition,so if you run tests on WindowsVM, RDP job will establish RDP connection and will keep it as long as needed, than tests will be executed
- use xfreerdp to establish rdp session with nohup to keep it after job finishes (pay attention to DESKTOP_RES as resolution can affect GUI tests):

> nohup xfreerdp -g DESKTOP_RES -u USER -p PASSWD --ignore-certificate
>   WIN_VM_IP

In our setup we have a python script which establishes RDP to all Win VMs before Win tests,it gets list of Win VM nodes from jenkins, for each Win VM node it tries to establish RDP and keep it in background (nohup):

```
  for i in WinVM:
    for retry in range(0,3):
        try:
            ip=get_IP_from_WinVM(i)
            print('RDP for: '+i+' ip:'+ip)
            proc=Popen(['nohup','xfreerdp','-g',args.res,'-u',args.user,'-p',args.pwd,'--ignore-certificate',ip], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE,stderr=PIPE )
            proc.stdin.write('y')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("Retrying RDP connection for "+i)
        else:
            break
```